# WSO2 CEP - Publisher Url From Property

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, publisher, wso2-cep

Can I set CEP publisher's URL from a Register property. For an example I want to add host url which I stored here

[image]

in url position in here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes capability is added recently but the feature is not available in latest release of CEP. You can build the pack from git hub and use it.`[1]` Once you go to advance publisher configurations , said configuration will be available for you.

`[1]`https://github.com/wso2/product-cep

Comment: sorry the capability is not available yet i have misread the question. We have improved it to read payload data from registry resources but not for the url. But you can set a dynamic event payload attribute as the http.url. eg:- if you have a url as a payload attribute you can set {{url}} for the http.url